# What type of file should I use for saving informations for my applications?

Tags: python, file, bots

I've write an application in `python` that saves informations on a txt file, but this is pretty slow, what type of file should I use for saving informations? And can I use the `open` function or I have to use another to make an high-efficiency transfer of data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a database. Sqlite3 comes with the default python package, and is good for small local projects.

Comment: If I use a remote database, and then host the application with Heroku connected to my github account, will I be able to access and download the files in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this answer to mark the question as SOLVED, see the first comment to get the real answer.